# Body style Javascript function seems slow

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a little Javascript function that changes the background color of the body. However, it seems very slow and jagged when it is run. Does anyone know why and how can I improve the code so it runs smoother?

Please see JSfiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2s2e737w/

```js
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

var fromTop = window.pageYOffset;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+fromTop/5 + ','+fromTop/2 +','+fromTop/3+")";
   });
```

```css
body{
 margin:0 ;
 padding: 0;
 height: 3000px;
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
}
p{
    color:white
}
```

```html
<p>
Scroll
</p>
```

Comment: You want to "debounce" it

Comment: Using [request animation frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) might help, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2s2e737w/1/)

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on scroll handler performance, its one of the trickier things in JavaScript. Just google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integer RGB values only, as decimal values are ignored by the browser and this leads to the perceived delay:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" +
    parseInt(fromTop/5, 10) + ',' +
    parseInt(fromTop/2, 10) + ',' +
    parseInt(fromTop/3, 10) + ")";
```

Percentage values are also acceptable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb